# Why does the neo4j process exit directly if hosted with Process.Start in .net?

Tags: .net, neo4j

I want to host neo4j inside a topshelf application, but I fail to do it properly. I do manage to start the install and run the service but when I do it with `Process.Start` the `java.exe` that I starts finish what it does so I loose track of the process id. Basically what I'm doing is:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pathToExe, arguments);
var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

`pathToExe` is the path to my java executable, and `arguments` are all the arguments needed to run neo4j. This do work and java is started as it should so I get a process chain looking something like

```
MyApp.exe --> Java (1) --> Java (2) --> conhost.exe
```

I'm having two `Java` is because neo4j starts the second one. And here is where I get into problem. When neo4j has started the second `Java` process the first one exits so my process chain is broken up into

```
MyApp.exe
Java (2) --> conhost.exe
```

That means I don't have a reference between my two processes any more. If I do install neo4j with `sc.exe` instead and the same arguments I get the following process chain:

```
Java (1) --> Java (2) --> conhost.exe
```

and here the `Java (1)` process never exits, which I don't know why. The difference is that in the first scenario neo4j is started by `Process.Start` from a service application, and in the second scenario the neo4j is started directly.

Any ideas to why this happens? The problem with this is that since I'm trying to do this as a service I can't get to the processes started by my service since they are "disconnected", and that's a problem when I try to stop or restart the service.

**Update:**
I did find one more difference in what's get started. When executable runs it starts a `conhost.exe` process as the same time as it starts the `Java (1)` process, both these processes exits at the same time.

Comment: Not sure perhaps @tathamoddie has got an ide.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a good answer to this, and I haven't seen anyone else providing it so I made a workaround.

To handle this in my scenario I just created a PID-file containing the process id of the process that I started in the service. That way I can stop all process spawned by the initial process I started when I try to stop the service.

This is not a complete solution since it won't work if my app spawns B that spawns C that spawns D and then both B and C exits. If both B and C exits I have no way to figure out what started D.